# C# Webbrowser HtmlElement Click invoke member doesnt work

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying to click on a button in a document but it does not work. I used `onclick`,`onfocus`,`onblur` methods but it does not work :(

My html is as below:

```
a href="#" id="aLabel"onfocus="this.className='btl-code-highlightText-Tree';" onclick="this.focus();" onblur="this.className='';"
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = this.WebBrowser.Document;
        try
        {
            HtmlElement Menu = htmlDoc.GetElementById("aLabel");

            if (Menu != null)
            {                 
                Menu.InvokeMember("onclick");       
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Is `Menu` null? If so are you waiting for a document complete event? Try `Menu.InvokeMember("click");  ` and put a `throw` in your catch block.

Comment: yes i am waiting for it

Answer (score 0):

IHTMLElement::onclick is a [property of VARIANT of IDispatch type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752306(v=vs.85).aspx), not a method so you can't invoke it.
since you know what onclick does, just call the focus method instead.